# Visual Studio Team Services build error due to nuget

Tags: tfs, nuget, azure-devops, tfsbuild

I am quite new to Visual Studio Team Services build and in the learning process.
I created a solution and created a build definition on Visual Studio Team Services. When I build it, I got these log details and then an error:

```
016-06-20T16:34:57.2842078Z Restoring NuGet package log4net.2.0.3.
2016-06-20T16:34:57.2892077Z Restoring NuGet package Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.1.1.1.
2016-06-20T16:34:57.3452071Z WARNING: Unable to find version '1.1.1' of  package 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs'.
2016-06-20T16:34:57.3462075Z   C:\Users\buildguest\AppData\Local\NuGet\Cache: Package 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.1.1.1' is not found on source 'C:\Users\buildguest\AppData\Local\NuGet\Cache'.
2016-06-20T16:34:57.3462075Z WARNING: Unable to find version '2.0.3' of package 'log4net'.
2016-06-20T16:34:57.3472076Z   C:\Users\buildguest\AppData\Local\NuGet\Cache: Package 'log4net.2.0.3' is not found on source 'C:\Users\buildguest\AppData\Local\NuGet\Cache'.
2016-06-20T16:34:57.4162071Z Restoring NuGet package Microsoft.Data.Edm.5.6.2.
2016-06-20T16:34:57.4432070Z WARNING: Unable to find version '5.6.2' of package 'Microsoft.Data.Edm'.
2016-06-20T16:34:57.5062068Z   C:\Users\buildguest\AppData\Local\NuGet\Cache: Package 'Microsoft.Data.Edm.5.6.2' is not found on source 'C:\Users\buildguest\AppData\Local\NuGet\Cache'.
```

The final Error:

```
2016-06-20T16:34:57.9012078Z ##[error]System.Exception: Unexpected exit code 1 returned from tool NuGet.exe
2016-06-20T16:34:57.9022088Z ##[error]   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.Internal.PowerShell.InvokeToolCmdlet.ProcessRecord()
2016-06-20T16:34:57.9022088Z ##[error]   at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord()
```

When I am running build locally, nuget never report any error. I don't really understand why the online version complains. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by the update of nuget.exe from 3.3 to 3.43. MS is working on a hotfix for this. Refer to this link for details: [Issues with Hosted Build in Visual Studio Team Services – 6/20 – Investigating](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsoservice/2016/06/20/issues-with-hosted-build-in-visual-studio-team-services-620-investigating/).

> Update: Monday, 20 June 2016 22:10 UTC
>
> The update to nuget.exe from 3.3 to 3.4.3 has been identified as the
>   root cause of the active restore problems.  We are working on a hotfix
>   to restore the previous nuget version on the build agents.
>
> We will update this post as the hotfix progresses.
>
> Sincerely, Sri Harsha
>
> Initial Update: Monday, 20 June 2016 19:40 UTC We are actively
>   investigating issues with the build agents of Visual Studio Team
>   services related to nuget  package restore. Some customers may
>   experience Build failures due to nuget packages being restored
>   incorrectly in the Build Agents.
>
> Next Update: Before 22:00 UTC We are actively working to resolve this
>   issue and apologize for any inconvenience.
>
> Sincerely, Manohar